# Disable autocmd project specific in vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I have given configuration to remove trailing white spaces in vim

```
  au BufWritePre *.rb :%s/\s\+$//e
  au BufWritePre *.html :%s/\s\+$//e
  au BufWritePre *.js :%s/\s\+$//e
  au BufWritePre *.jsx :%s/\s\+$//e
  au BufWritePre *.json :%s/\s\+$//e
```

**PROBLEM**

I have a project in which multiple developers are working and it's a big one. I don't want to cause lots of conflicts by removing existing trailing whitespace in this project.

**EXPECTED**

I want to disable this configuration for that specific project only. Lets say my project is in `~/work/projectA`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you could do all that with a single autocommand:

```
au BufWritePre *.{rb,html,js,jsx,json} %s/\s\+$//e
```

Second, you should put it inside a proper "augroup":

```
augroup TrailingSpaces
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePre *.{rb,html,js,jsx,json} %s/\s\+$//e
augroup END
```

Third, you could disable that group for that specific project with another (maybe a bit heavy-handed) autocommand:

```
augroup SpecialProject
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead ~/work/projectA/**/* autocmd! TrailingSpaces
augroup END
```

Fourth, losing your cursor position after `:%s/\s\+$//e` is not fun. I would do something like that if I were you:

```
augroup TrailingSpaces
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePre *.{rb,html,js,jsx,json} let w:wv = winsaveview() | %s/\s\+$//e | call winrestview(w:wv)
augroup END
```

See `:help winsaveview()`.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. I was trying with augroup, but it was not working. looking at your code I found that I was missing recursive directory `/**/*`. Thank you very much romainl

Comment: Wouldn't this clear the `TrailingSpaces` group once a file from `projectA` is opened? Thus stopping `TrailingSpaces` from working in non-`projectA` directories after a `projectA` file . Maybe instead set a buffer-local variable like `let b:no_strip = 1` and then add a conditional to the `TrailingSpaces` autocmd. e.g. if !get(b:, 'no_strip') | ... | endif`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to configure this is using https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim.

**Global Configuration**

Add global `~/.editorconfig` to set global editorconfig

```
[*]
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

**Project Specific Configuration**

`~/work/projectA/.editorconfig`

```
[*]
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

Without breaking anything. and remove `trim trailing whitespace` code from `.vimrc`

```
  " au BufWritePre *.rb :%s/\s\+$//e
  " au BufWritePre *.html :%s/\s\+$//e
  " au BufWritePre *.js :%s/\s\+$//e
  " au BufWritePre *.jsx :%s/\s\+$//e
  " au BufWritePre *.json :%s/\s\+$//e
```

for list of configuration: http://editorconfig.org/

Answer (score 1):

You could also fix the mappings to check a configuration variable. That variable could then be set in [local vimrcs](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc/), or in an `.editorconfig` file with the a [hook I've implemented in lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Project.md#3113-from-your-editorconfig-file), or even with autocommands (which I don't recommend)

For intance, my autocommand (for vim) executes a [function](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/autoload/lh/vim/maintain.vim#L123) that tests whether `b:vim_maintain.remove_trailing`, [`p:vim_maintain.remove_trailing`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Project.md) or `g:vim_maintain.remove_trailing` is set to 1 before doing the substitution.

```
function! lh#vim#maintain#_save_pre_hook() abort
  let pos = getpos('.')
  let cleanup = lh#on#exit()
        \.register('call setpos(".", '.string(pos).')')
  try
    if lh#option#get('vim_maintain.remove_trailing', 1)
      :silent! %s/\s\+$//
    endif
    if s:must_update_time_stamp()
      ......
     endif
  finally
    call cleanup.finalize()
  endtry
endfunction
```

Speaking of editor config, more simply, it has an option to decide whether trailing whitespaces shall be removed. It'll be great for projects you share with other people, however, you'll have to patch all your personal projects to add a `.editorconfig` file.

Comment: Since you brought up plugins, [EditorConfig](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim) has a `trim_trailing_whitespace` feature

Comment: @PeterRincker. Indeed, that's what I was speaking about in my last sentence ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Just to throw another plugin solution into the ring:*

My [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967) provides a robust solution (that doesn't have the mentioned problems of changing the view, clobbering the search pattern, and so on). (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)

My plugin can be turned off for certain buffers via a `b:DeleteTrailingWhitespace` flag. You can make an exception for that particular project with the `:autocmd` provided by the other answers, or (if you want to localize the exception to the project itself, so that it survives file system moves, or even version control clones) use a *local vimrc* plugin (for example the [localrc plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393) (especially with [my own enhancements](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-localrc/tree/enhancements)), which even allows local filetype-specific configuration). With that, you can put the `:let b:DeleteTrailingWhitespace = 0` command into a `.lvimrc` in the root of that project, and that's it.